# How to let Ansible run a command with host as argument locally

Tags: ansible

I installed servers at multiple hosts using ansible playbook. the hosts are defined at inventory file:

```
[services]
host_ip1
host_ip1
...
```

Now I need to test if each host works properly using command:

```
service-cli -h <host_ip1> -p 6380 ping
...
```

How do I write that using ansible? it is for sure ansible will run the command at local not remote, Then how do I pass the host_ipX to ansible?

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what error is it producing? Are you aware of the `delegate_to:` and `with_items:` keywords?

Comment: Hi, mdaniel, I know how to use delegate_to: 127.0.0.1, I do not know how to get the ip of inventory file using with_items, what keywords should I set? services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know how to use delegate_to: 127.0.0.1, I do not know how to get the ip of inventory file using with_items, what keywords should I set? services?

Your use case is literally documented in the [`extract` examples](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-values-from-arrays-or-hashtables)

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: service-cli -h {{ item }} -p 6380 ping
  with_items: '{{ groups["services"] | map("extract", hostvars, "ansible_host") }}'
  delegate_to: localhost
  # this is required if you want the task as part of a playbook
  # that contains "hosts: all"
  run_once: yes
```

or, as an alternative to the "run_once" you can isolate that as its own play:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: service-cli -h {{ item }} -p 6380 ping
    with_items: '{{ groups["services"] | map("extract", hostvars, "ansible_host") }}'

- hosts: all
  ... # and now back to normal life
```